# Worker threads in express application

Tags: node.js, multithreading, express, backend, node-worker-threads

I have an express backend application, which listens for http requests from a web application. This backend application is running on AWS ECS Fargate.

So my question is, does it makes sense use multithreading, worker-threads in Node.js, in this backend application? There are both CPU intensive and non-intensive functions in the endpoints. For instance should I just distribute any incoming request right away ,regardless of the intensity of the call, to other threads so that Main thread is never blocked? Or should I only use multithreading on intensive jobs etc.

Any suggestion, pros and cons on this topic is very much appreciated.

Comment: JavaScript is asynchronous. Use threads only for CPU intensive execution.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the relevance between Javascript being asynchronous and your suggestion. It would be awesome if you could clarify. Also for instance by intensive do you mean timewise locking or resourcewise locking. For instance if I have 100 http requests to send they are not resourcewise intensive but timewise it is. So what should I do in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Questions like this ultimately only really get answered by profiling the system under representative load.  This is because our guestimates about what takes CPU and how much are just rarely very good - this stuff has to be measured to really know.

That said, there are some general design guidelines you could consider:

1. If you have specific requests that you believe in advance are likely to be CPU heavy, then you may want to consider putting those into a queue that is served by a pool of threads.
2. If you have specific requests that you believe in advance are really just doing non-blocking I/O, then those don't need to get complicated at all by threading.  The main thread can likely handle those just fine.
3. If only a relatively small fraction of your requests are CPU heavy, the simplest design may be to use the nodejs clustering module and just let it spread your requests out among CPUs figuring that this by itself (without any other major design changes) will get any CPU-bound requests off the main loop.  If a high percentage of your requests are CPU-bound and you want to prioritize the non-CPU requests so they are always quick, then you'd probably be better with  the thread pool that CPU-heavy requests are passed off to so the non-CPU heavy requests aren't held up by them.

> So my question is, does it makes sense use multithreading, worker-threads in Node.js, in this backend application?

Yes, in some circumstances.  But, when to add this extra layer of complication really depends upon the specific metrics of CPU usage in your requests.

> For instance should I just distribute any incoming request right away ,regardless of the intensity of the call, to other threads so that Main thread is never blocked?   Or should I only use multithreading on intensive jobs etc.

This depends upon how you want to prioritize different requests.  If you want requests prioritized in a FIFO order, where each one gets to start in order based on when it arrived, regardless of what type of request, then yes you can just distribute all requests to threads.  In fact, it's probably easier to just use the clustering module for this because that's what it does.  If, on the other hand, you want non-CPU-heavy requests to always run quick and not have to wait behind CPU-heavy requests, then you may want to push only the CPU-heavy requests into a queue that is processed by a thread pool.  This, then allows the main thread to work on the non-CPU-heavy requests immediately regardless of how many CPU-heavy requests are currently crunching away in the thread pool.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer it looks great. I want FIFO for sure in my application so you say I should use just node:cluster to distribute the work, which I researched and it seems very suitable for what I want. But pushing it further, would it be ok if I use clusters to distribute requests, and specifically use worker threads for time consuming requests? Just to note what  the time consuming request in this case is smh like waiting for 20-30 http requests to the database.

Comment: @AhmetYazıcı - Mixing the cluster model with worker threads may not help you.  The idea with the cluster module is to configure it for as many clusters as CPU cores that you have.  Once you've done that, your clusters will utilize all the CPU cores in the system.  Adding additional worker threads in each individual clustered process for distributing CPU-heavy requests probably won't increase total throughput because you don't have more CPU cores to really take advantage of the additional threads.  I think you probably want to pick one model or the other, not mix them.